# Is a fire collar for internal pipes required if my house was built before the (UK) regulation?

Tags: building-regulations, building, fire

I've had a surveyor round my property tutting a lot at the fact a fire collar was not fit around an internal soil pipe that runs from the internal garage to the above floors. I understand his concerns in relation to fire passing through the gap surrounding the pipe.

My question being is: when was this regulation and if my property was built before the updated regulations do I have to fit this?

I've found this in regards to the collar but I'm struggling to understand a yes/no answer: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/fire-safety-approved-document-b

Comment: My understanding of UK law is that if currently-non-compliant work can be proved to have been done before the relevant part of the building regs came into force it is exempt. However, IANAL, and fire-safety is perhaps the most stringent of all the regulations (with good reason). How much would it cost to fit a fire-collar? Surely the best option would be to just fit it, and be done, rather than trying to see if you can *'get away with'* not doing so?

Comment: the collar itself is about £20 - getting access to where it would need to be fit is the difficult part and would require ripping down part of a false ceiling...and not only that there are other conduits and pipes that run through the same hole...so a fire collar might not fit adequately. I'm selling the property and this wasn't something picked up by my surveyor only 3 years ago.

Trust me, if it was easy to fit and I wasn't mid sale then it would've been something I'd look into sorting